# Bootstrap 4 img-circle class doesn't seem to exist

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a website in HTML5 and Bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to turn a square image into a circle. In Bootstrap 3 this was easily do-able with `.img-circle`, but now I can't seem to get it to work and I can't find any answers online.
Has Bootstrap dropped the img-circle class or is my code messed up?

It goes something like this:

```
<!-- Within a tab-content div --> 
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <img src="img/gallery2.JPG" class="img-circle" alt="HelPic">
</div>
```

Hope somebody can help me out :)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

It's now called `rounded-circle` as [explained here in the BS4 docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/borders/)

```
<img src="img/gallery2.JPG" class="rounded-circle">
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/FelvOGA7Xn)

Comment: but that is not a circle. Isn't it oval?

Comment: If the image isn't square it will be an oval.

Answer (score 6):

In **Bootstrap 4** and **Bootstrap 5** it was **.rounded-circle**

Usage :

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <img src="img/gallery2.JPG" class="rounded-circle" alt="HelPic>
</div>
```

See migration [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#images) from bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Now the class is this

```html
 <img src="img/img5.jpg" width="200px" class="rounded-circle float-right">
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here via google because I couldn't get rounded edges on images, here's how I solved;

```
.rounded-xl {
   border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```